# Change default Browser Mode in Internet Explorer 9/10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm running the Windows 8 Developer Preview, and I would like to make IE10's DEFAULT browser mode to be Internet Explorer 9. I can change it with F12, but it always goes back to IE10 browser mode when I restart the browser. Is there any way to make IE10 start up running with Internet Explorer 9 browser mode?

Comment: You realize this is pre-beta software that barely functions as intended.

Comment: I realize that :) I'm dual booting with win7, but am spending a lot of time in Win 8 recently. I was just wondering whether there was a way to make my experience better